# Not understanding string format() method with decimal in ouput

Tags: python, string-formatting

I was going through the basic mathematical operation in python terminal and using format to manage the output.

I tried to generate output with the 10 decimal places.

> print('{0:.10f}'.format(1.0/3))
>
> > Got this output 0.3333333333

Again I tried to generate output with the 20 decimal places

> print('{0:.20f}'.format(1.0/3))
>
> > Got this output as 0.33333333333333331483

I think this should return 0.3333333333333333333

Why format function is not working as desired.

Answer (score 3):

The format function is working normally. 
This is mainly because of the limitations of programming languages regarding floating point precision when producing decimals from division.

I encourage that you read about that here. 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html